# Ansible installed with Git? Can I safely delete it?

Tags: ansible, redhat

I have an Ansible installation on a host. It is showing me a `hostname [devel]$` prompt as if I am in a Git branch. When I do a `git log` it shows me a bunch of commits from what looks like the ansible git repository. `git branch` shows a single branch ("* devel")

- Does this mean Ansible has been installed using Git?
- Can I safely delete the `.git` directory to carry on using Ansible as I normally would?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems like Ansible has been installed from the Ansible git repository. If you delete the `.git` directory you would delete the git repository. Ansible should work if you do that but I can't think of any good reason do to that. If you keep the git repository updating will be much easier. Also if you use the `devel` branch it is more likely that you will run into bugs. So don't do that. If you want to install Ansible in a simple way without using the git repository I would recommend to use the `pip` repository like this:

```
pip install ansible
```

Comment: I ran `sudo install ansible` which has upgraded the install. I want to initialise a new Git repo for my Ansible projects, so I don't want anything additional.

Comment: There is no need to store playbooks and role in the same directory as Ansible. Just make sure that `roles_path` variable is set correct in [ansible.cfg](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#roles-path)